# Get the directory from a variable in a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows batch file, having a variable `%location%` where is stored a full path (eg: `e:\root_dir\sub1\sub2`), how can one extract the full path excluding the drive letter? Result should be stored in a variable and for previous example result would be be`\root_dir\sub1\sub2`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('%location%\') DO SET Result=%%~pA
```

Result of `%location%` being `e:\root_dir\sub1\sub2` would yield `%Result%` = `\root_dir\sub1\sub2\`.